# How to update another sheet in App Script using openById() method

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my code can you help what did I do wrong with my code:  the function texFinder(sheet = "ASC", findText = "abc12345"){...} works fine but it is not working when I call the fun.

```
function textFinder(sheet, findText) {

  var sheetstolook = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ifE_iXM9RJJBiHOQdpSlKnvGcnkvFk').getSheetByName(sheet).activate();

  var SHTvalues = sheetstolook.createTextFinder(findText).findAll();

  var result = SHTvalues.map(r => ({ row: r.getRow(), col: r.getColumn() }));

  var toupdate = sheetstolook.getRange(result[0].row, result[0].col + 1).getValue();

  sheetstolook.getRange(result[0].row, result[0].col + 1).setValue(toupdate - 1);

  if (parseInt(toupdate) < 0) {
    sheetstolook.getRange(result[0].row, result[0].col + 1).setBackgrounds('red');
  }

}
function onEdit(e){
...
    else if (col == 9 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 5).getValue().toUpperCase() === "FRM") {
    
    
    
        var shsearch = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 4).getValue().toUpperCase();
        var shTxt = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 9 ).getValue();
        
    
        textFinder(shsearch, shTxt);
        
      }
}
```

Comment: What you want to update in that sheet, what's your end objective from that code above?, as much i understand you're trying to replace text, right? Also remove `.activate()` from because it won't have any meaning while using it with `openById()`

Comment: my objective is to update another spreadsheet by using openById() when the current specific cell is updated... still not working I removed .activate()

Comment: SO there is sheet A and Sheet B, and both sheet are same, you want to update entire data of sheet A whenever it is edited to Sheet B, so that both the sheet have same data, right? is it your end objective?

Comment: There is spreadsheet A and Spreadsheet B. I want to update the specific value when the data is entered on spreadsheet A of sheets to update spreadSheet B value by finding the entered key on spreadsheet A ... It's like inventory management to deduct the stock value of sheet B when new data is inserted on Sheet B but Sheet A and B are in a separate workbook.

Comment: According to me the more ethical way to do it, is by using `importrange` and use `formulas` to achieve what you're asking, if data is large, and `importrange` is causing issues, you can set a `onEdit` trigger and that can actually dump the sheet A data into sheet B using `getValue` and `setValue` methods, because what you're doing currently will make your process very slow and increase the chances of failures .

Comment: my point is to update the data value(count) of worksheet B when item xxx is inserted on sheet A one at a time... not importing the whole sheet from worksheet A to B ... I hope you understand me.